# Detect if another application was installed/uninstalled in a jailbroken iDevice

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, jailbreak

I want to detect when another application was installed/uninstalled and save the time to a database at the moment of execution.

I know this is possible in Android using broadcastreceiver and I want to know if this can be done in iOS using a jailBroken device because I believe this is not possible in a non-jailBroken device.

I hope someone could help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Recently was having the same problem.

You need to write SpringBoard tweak. In it you observe notification `SBInstalledApplicationsDidChangeNotification` from local notification center (`CFNotificationCenterGetLocalCenter` or `[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]`). User info dictionary will contain:

- `SBInstalledApplicationsRemovedBundleIDs` key contains array of bundle IDs of uninstalled applications.
- `SBInstalledApplicationsModifiedBundleIDs` key contains array of bundle IDs of updated applications.
- `SBInstalledApplicationsAddedBundleIDs` key contains array of bundle IDs of installed applications.

Obviously that way you can log every time applications are installed/uninstalled/updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if an application is installed by using its bundle id

```
BOOL isInstalled = [[LSApplicationWorkspace defaultWorkspace] applicationIsInstalled:@"com.app.identifier"];

if (isInstalled) {
    // app is installed }
else {
    // app is not installed
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to check if an application got installed you can maybe count the items inside `user` of `com.apple.mobile.installation.plist` it holds all the information about installed apps.

You can write the number of apps inside a plist then later check back and compare the results?

```
// get apps count
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installation.plist"];
int numberOfApps = [[dict objectForKey: @"User"] count];
NSLog(@"Count: %i",numberOfApps);

// Save apps count inside a plist
NSString *path = @"/var/mobile/AppsCount.plist"; 
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSMutableDictionary *data;
 if ([fm fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
     data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
}
else {
    // If the file doesn’t exist, create an empty dictionary
    data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
}
[data setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:numberOfApps] forKey:@"savedAppsCount"];
[data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
[data release];
```

And then to compare old counts with the new apps count:

```
// get current number of apps
NSString *path = @"/var/mobile/AppsCount.plist";
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installation.plist"];
int numberOfApps = [[dict objectForKey: @"User"] count];

// retrieve old app count and compare to new ones
NSMutableDictionary *retrieveCounts = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
int oldAppCount = [[retrieveCounts objectForKey:@"savedAppsCount"] intValue];
if (oldAppCount < numberOfApps) { 
    NSLog(@"NEW APP GOT INSTALLED");
     }
else if (oldAppCount > numberOfApps) {
    NSLog(@"AN APP GOT UNINSTALLED");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"NOTHING GOT INSTALLED OR UNINSTALLED");
}
[retrieveCounts release];
```

But that doesn't give you the time, it just checks if a new app got installed

There might be a better way of doing that, but that's what came into my mind.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I want to check everytime an application is installed or uninstalled and I want to check all application, not just one. This is not the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Thank you for a very nice answer. If only I can run this in the background or put it in a thread and get the time in the NSLog part this might be the answer I'm looking for. Can I do that with iOS?

Comment: I don't think you can run this in background on iOS, and i have no idea how can we get the time, Sorry.